# Zlib DEFLATE decompression bomb

Tags: appsec, attacks, denial-of-service, compression

Can you give me an example of a short data string that, when decompressed using Zlib's DEFLATE method, expands to something much much longer?

More precisely: what is the nastiest decompression bomb that one can build for Zlib's DEFLATE?  The figure of merit here is the compression ratio.  If the compressed file is *n* bytes long, and after decompression it yields something *m* bytes long, then the compression ratio is *m/n*.  I am looking for something that maximizes the compression ratio, where hopefully the compressed data is very short.  Can anyone give me an example of such a decompression bomb?

---

Related: [This post](https://www.bamsoftware.com/hacks/deflate.html) claims that DEFLATE can asymptotically approach a compression ratio of 1032; is that the best one can do, or can one achieve a higher compression ratio if we pick a carefully chosen sequence of compressed bytes?  Libpng [defends](http://libpng.sourceforge.net/decompression_bombs.html) against decompression bombs by imposing resource limits, but they don't give a concrete example of a specific decompression bomb.  See also [zip bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), the corresponding attack but for the ZIP file format.

Answer (score 11):

The source of the "1032:1" figure is given on the [zlib site](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_tech.html) where it is told that:

> The limit comes from the fact that one length/distance pair can represent at most 258 output bytes. A length requires at least one bit and a distance requires at least one bit, so two bits in can give 258 bytes out, or eight bits in give 1032 bytes out. A dynamic block has no length restriction, so you could get arbitrarily close to the limit of 1032:1.

This is a quote from Mark Adler, one of the two designers of zlib. Having myself implemented a library for Deflate, I can confirm that, given how [the algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) works, this asymptotic limit is indeed true (you cannot go beyond, but you can get as close as you wish). Deflate works by encoding "copies": each element is either a new byte, or a copy of a past sequence; copies can overlap (i.e. you can copy a sequence of length 30 at distance 4, yielding 15 times the past sequence of 4 bytes); Huffman codes are applied on the sequence of elements. To get a minimal length "copy" you need it to overlap a lot, and each copy is worth at most 258 bytes. So the data which is to be compressed will have to be a long string of identical bytes.

As @Steffen says, compressing with `gzip` a long sequence of zeros will yield a more than 1000:1 compression ratio. It does not have to be zeros; any sequence consisting of the same byte value over and over will do the trick; but a Linux machine has a `/dev/zero`, not a `/dev/fortytwo`.

"Compression bombs" were already active quite a long time ago; I saw it employed to kill Netscape back in 1996 (at that time, Netscape handled background pictures, but Mosaic did not; a very small GIF file could encode a huge background, which Netscape allocated as a single big pixmap in the X11 server).

Answer (score 4):

zlib deflate is used by gzip. To create ab 10k bomb out of 10M input you might use

```
dd if=/dev/zero  bs=1024 count=$((10*1024)) | gzip -9 > bomb.gz
```

And I think the post is right in claiming that you have a maximum ratio of about 1000. More information are at http://www.aerasec.de/security/advisories/decompression-bomb-vulnerability.html (old) but http://blog.cyberis.co.uk/2013_08_01_archive.html shows that most modern browsers still no have protection against it.

Comment: Why *should* browsers protect against it? Once they start decompressing the file, they'll know if they're going to hit a resource limit, and cancel the operation if it's going to take too much memory. It's not clear to me that clicking on a link and getting a 10k file which expands to 10M is any worse than getting a 10M uncompressed file.

Comment: @DanLenski: if you read the links I have provided you will see that some browsers don't cancel the decompression if it takes too much memory. It does not matter if they would have a protection once they have extracted the 10MB (or 1GB for more bombing). The need to detect the problem while decompressing and not while processing the (decompressed) content.

Comment: Fair point. It's definitely a bug to only check the space requirement *before* decompression, rather than during it.